# Append element in linkedlist without duplication

Tags: data-structures, singly-linked-list

Im in the first stage of learning LINKEDLIST in data structure. I need an algorithm which explains the append of an element without duplication.

Answer (score 0):

As you are learning **linkedlist** -
To search an element in **linkedlist**, a linear search is required - looping the **linkedlist** to find the element.

Now, to insert a non-duplicate element, the **linkedlist** need to be searched once, to check if the element is in the **linkedlist** or not.
If the element is not in **linkedlist** then, we should append the element.
So,
You should try this approach,

```
insert(x,linkedlist){

    1. Check if x in linkedlist
       <code to search x in linked list>

    2. If not found then append x
       <code to append x in linked list>
}
```

There is another efficient approach using **HashSet**, As a beginner, I would not recommend this now. Please comment if you want this approach also.